# UIProgressView doesn't change height after changing appearance, but change after rotating device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiprogressview, uiappearance

I've set track image and progress image using `[UIProgressView appearance]`. Images set, but height of `UIProgressView` didn't change. It changes only after rotating device to lanscape. Where could be problem? Setting `UIProgressView's` frame doesn't help.

```
//image size 13x13 px.
[[UIProgressView appearance] setProgressImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UploadingProgress_1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)]];
[[UIProgressView appearance] setTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading_1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)]];
```

**SOLVED** with `[[UIProgressView appearance] setFrame:]` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view (or at least the rectangle you care about) is being redrawn when you set the appearance.  Call the method `setNeedsDisplay` whenever you set the appearance.  The height of your UIProgressView would change on autorotation, because your views are re-laid out and redrawn when you rotate.